# anaconda does not launch the correct python

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I have a strange problem with anaconda on my Mac OSX running El Capitan.

I just tried to create a python 2.7 environment as follows:

```
conda create -n dato-env python=2.7 anaconda
```

This downloads and installs the package.

Now, I do:

```
source activate dato-env
```

which results in:

```
discarding /Users/xargon/anaconda/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/dato-env/bin to PATH
```

Now when I launch python, it launches the system python 3...

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:18:23)
```

Looking at the path variable, I see:

```
/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/dato-env/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:
/usr/local/fsl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

An when I launch with the full path:

```
/Users/xargon/anaconda/envs/dato-env/bin/python
```

It launches the correct python:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58)
```

Comment: Is it possible you have a shell alias defined in .profile or .bashrc?  These take precedence over the path.  Type `alias` to see the list of aliases.

Comment: Damn! @NeapolitanThat was it! Thanks so much!

Comment: The irony? I forgot to unset the alias after testing and was bitten by this not two hours later!  Took a bit of time to figure out...

Comment: haha. That is funny.